# How do I override a method when the compiler says it's "not found in base class"?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a custom component I am creating which is derived from `TCustomListView`.

I need to override a method, specifically the `GetImageIndex` method, but I cannot seem to access it.

The component I am making needs to behave like a `TListView` but without a lot of the published properties and methods it has, as I will be creating my own in the component hence I derive it from `TCustomListView` instead.

In my component I tried accessing the `GetImageIndex` like so:

```
TMyListView = class(TCustomListView)
  strict protected
    procedure GetImageIndex(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
end;

procedure TMyListView.GetImageIndex(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  inherited;
  // Make my changes
end;
```

Obviously the above is shortened down for the purpose of the example.

I am met with a compilation error of:

> Method `GetImageIndex` not found in base class

How do I access and override this method from my component? These type of methods will not be published or available at runtime as I will be doing the changes the component needs, so I would like to know how to access and change it?

---

**Solution**

Based off the information provided by David Heffernan, I have a working solution. He did provide code to one way of achieving this and information to another way, the code provided still proved troublesome for me so I attempted to do option 1 that he stated.

Here it is:

```
protected
    procedure GetImageIndex(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem); // note not to override
```

and the constructor:

```
constructor TMyListView.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  OnGetImageIndex := GetImageIndex;
end;
```

If this is still wrong please let me know but from quick initial tests I see no problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `TCustomListView.GetImageIndex` method is a non-virtual method. You cannot override it.

Your options for customisation here are:

1. Supply an event handler for the `OnGetImageIndex` event.
2. Handle the `LVN_GETDISPINFOA` and `LVN_GETDISPINFOW` notification codes in a `CN_NOTIFY` message handler, and supply your own customised behaviour there.

The former option should be obvious. The latter option looks like this:

```
type
  TMyListView = class(TCustomListView)
  protected
    procedure CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyLV); message CN_NOTIFY;
  end;
....
procedure TMyListView.CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyLV);
begin
  case Message.NMHdr.code of
  LVN_GETDISPINFOA, LVN_GETDISPINFOW:
    ; // add your customisation here
  else
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```

Note that you may choose to call inherited in all scenarios, and then apply customisation in addition to that. It all depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response David, and again as feared the solution is a mind boggling one. Now I honestly dont expect anyone to just write the code for me, but if I can understand how you determined the problem and you came to a solution that would be more beneficial. Copying code answers is one thing, but identifying the task and working out the solution is much more valuable and its this task solving side of things I need to work on, not just copying answers.

Comment: Well, identifying the fact that `TCustomListView.GetImageIndex` is a private non-virtual method was simple. That's stated clearly in the source code for the control. The next step was to look to see what `GetImageIndex` does. Again, from the source code, it fires the `OnGetImageIndex` event. Finally, `GetImageIndex` is called just once, in the handler code for `LVN_GETDISPINFOA, LVN_GETDISPINFOW`. It's all in the source code.

Comment: Well when you put it like that it does sound simple, but for me I get lost in code rather easy. I have 2 problems here, the first is `The former option should be obvious.`, to me not so obvious. So option 1 of supplying an event handle is also trivial. Option 2 looks good, but then how I get a hold of `Item: TListItem`, do I need to copy chunks of code from the original Listview source?

Comment: You can read the source code and the MSDN docs to find out how to implement option 2. Option 1 is an event handler. You already know how to implement events like `OnClick`. It's nothing more complicated than that.

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can do with the help provided and will come back later with my progress.

Comment: Option 2 looks rather complex as it requires bringing original source code into my custom component, or at least that is the impression I got.

Comment: The problem with option 1 is that consumers of the class cannot use the event since you've hijacked it. I guess you must make sure you don't publish it. Anyway, surely I answered the question you asked.

Comment: The event does not need to be published this time so no worries there. Yes I will accept thank you, just wanted to give chance for others to comment or leave a solution.

Comment: Thanks. For the question you asked there's no answer other than the first paragraph that I wrote.

Comment: I suppose you're right, just I used to get into the habit of accepting the first answer and moving along without considering what others have contributed and therefore I usually miss a lot of valuable information. In this case the answer was very simple, apart from option 2 which proved trivial for me despite the code provided. Thanks again David for your help.

Comment: I didn't mean that I wanted you to accept. More that I think I'd already said all that I had to say on the original topic.